# Arranging circles into rows

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to take an array of length 50 and have some control over how these circles are appended when the data is bound to them with d3. In my case with 50 circles, I'd want 5 rows and 10 columns of circles. The best I could come up with would be the following snippet here:

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var circData = new Array(50);

var rowMarker = 1;

graphGroup.selectAll('circle')
    .data(circData)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d,i) { return i*30})
    .attr('cy', function(d,i) {
      if (i%10) {
        rowMarker += 1;
      }
      return rowMarker*30;
    })
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style('fill', 'gray');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

What should happen is that `rowMarker` reaches a new integer increment every time the function progress ten elements deeper as measured by the index `i`. Yet what seems to be happening is the circles are being appended such that their values of `y` attributes are more than what one would expect to have if `rowMarker` is only updated every row.

### Question

Is there a way to help me map my circles to the data in a 5x10 "circle matrix" as I have attempted above? If so, what logic is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that this...

```
if (i%10)
```

... will be `true` for everything except the first `i` value (that is, zero) and multiples of 10.

But, besides that, your approach seems unnecessarily complicated. You can simply set the maximum number of columns...

```
var maxColumn = 10;
```

... and then use the modulo operator for both `x` and `y` values:

```
.attr('cx', function(d, i) {
    return (i % maxColumn) * 30
})
.attr('cy', function(d, i) {
    return (~~(i / maxColumn) % maxColumn) * 30
})
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var margins = {
  top: 20,
  bottom: 300,
  left: 30,
  right: 100
};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width + margins.left + margins.right;
var totalHeight = height + margins.top + margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', totalWidth)
  .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

var circData = new Array(50);

var maxColumn = 10;

graphGroup.selectAll('circle')
  .data(circData)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
    return (i % maxColumn) * 30
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
    return (~~(i / maxColumn) % maxColumn) * 30
  })
  .attr('r', 10)
  .style('fill', 'gray');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```